# Change the Increment Value of HTML Number Input - Decimals

Tags: html

Is there any way to change how much a number is incremented when using the up/down arrows on a HTML number input form?

```
<input type="number" step="any" value="0.00000000"></input>
```

I'm working with tiny numbers, it would be nice if the up/down arrows incremented just 0.00000001 at a time, instead of a whole number.

- 0.00000000
- 0.00000001
- 0.00000002
- 0.00000003

Instead of

- 0.00000000
- 1
- 2
- 3

I doubt very much if there is an easy way to do this, just though I'd ask and see if anyone else has a workaround or method as I'm sure many people experience a similar issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The [`step` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-step) is for this. Your code now has the value `any`, which means that any values are accepted and the step size is the default, 1. Replace it by a specific number to set the granularity and the step size. Example:

```html
<input type="number" step="0.00000001" value="0.00000000">
```

Note: The end tag `</input>` is invalid in HTML syntax for HTML5. In XHTML syntax it is allowed, but “self-closing tags” are recommended instead of it, e.g. `<input type="number" step="0.00000001" value="0.00000000" />`.