# How to set value in a number input type?

Tags: php, html

I want to set value of each number in a number textbox. Example, the value of number 1 is equal to 0.125, 2 = 0.250, 3 = 0.375, and so on.
This is the code.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="60"/>
```

Comment: <input type="number" min="0" max="60"></input>

Comment: set value="0.125" etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the Increment Value of HTML Number Input - Decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003148/change-the-increment-value-of-html-number-input-decimals)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="60" value="0.125" />
<input type="number" min="0" max="60" value="0.250" />
<input type="number" min="0" max="60" value="0.375" />
```

Also, input elements are self-closing, no need to add the extra closing tag.
Hope this helps!

Comment: ^^ This should work OP.  Remember to pick a correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the step attribute,

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="60" step="0.125"></input>
```

Refer this link,
    https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp

I hope this are your helpfull,

Comment: that's not what he wants.  `step` only allows input values which are increments of `step`.  He just needs `value=0.125`,etc.  I presume he's doing input * value